# Completion from Chat Completions API (openai) format

Tags: node.js, openai-api, completion

I want to have a completion for an api request to openapi (gpt-4), in a json format, or as similar as possible to it.

Thing is, I already tried to put this format in a separate json, tried to use the json format as a parameter (but apparently, it doesn't work for the model I am using), already tried many things. The closest I got was designing it inside the prompt, but the api breaks lines automatically, I have no idea how to remove it (tried the stop: ['\n'], tried a regex, but nothing is working).

Anyone would give me a light? Pretty sure something stupid would solve it, but I ran out of ideas so far...

I am using the gpt-4 model.

Here's the prompt I am using today:

```
 const prompt = `Create a question about ${x}, the answer should be in below format:
  {

    "title": "Title. Should be...",
    "description": "Description. Should have...",
    "code_snippet: "Should show as...", 
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"],
    "options": [
      {"text": "Opção A", "correct": true},
      {"text": "Opção B", "correct": true},
      {"text": "Opção C": "correct": true},
      {"text": "Opção D": "correct": false},
    ]
    "feedback_title": "should be this...",
    "feedback_text": "should be that...",
  }`
```

Comment: [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185628/how-to-prompt-chatgpt-api-to-give-completely-machine-readable-responses-without?rq=2) might steer you in the right direction. ([Function Calling](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/function-calling))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API: How do I enable JSON mode using the gpt-4-vision-preview model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434808/openai-api-how-do-i-enable-json-mode-using-the-gpt-4-vision-preview-model)